# Building a WebAPI for an N-tier web application - appropriate practices for error handling?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a web application with the following layers:

1. Client(s)
2. WebAPI
3. Services
4. Repository
5. Core

I'm not sure where to put error handling though.  Within the webAPI controllers, should I just have try/catch statements?  Is it ok to throw errors in the services/repository code?  I'm trying to avoid passing any data to the client, other than some friendly error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Business errors should be handled in your service layer (for example things like username already exists). Putting try/catch statements in all your controller actions could quickly become cumbersome and lead to repetitive code. You may take a look at the [`custom error handling article`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling) which provides examples of handling various errors in the Web API such as custom error filters (deriving from the [`ExceptionFilterAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.exceptionfilterattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) class and overriding the `OnException` method).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom exception type that would be intercepted by an ExceptionFilter or http module. It would set the HTTP status code and description. Optionally, it can also return a serialized object with the error data.

Other exception types would return status code 500.